Separation of variables
Is it possible to replicate the same procedure of placing the functions that depend on $r$ on one side of the equation and on the other side leave the equations that depend on $\theta$ in Mathematica? (except the function $\Sigma$). In particular, let the following expression:
$$ 1=\left(\delta+\left(\frac{\Upsilon E^2+4 a M r E L}{\Sigma \Delta}\right)-\left(\frac{\Delta-a^2 \sin ^2(\theta)}{\Sigma \Delta \sin ^2(\theta)}\right) L^2\right)\left(\frac{\Sigma}{\Delta} \dot{r}^2+\Sigma \dot{\theta}^2 \right) $$
where $\Sigma  =r^2+a^2 \cos ^2(\theta)$, $\Delta  =r^2+a^2-2 M r$, $ \Upsilon =\left(r^2+a^2\right)^2-a^2 \Delta \sin ^2(\theta)$. I want to get:
$$ r^2 \delta+\frac{1}{\Delta}\left(\left(r^2+a^2\right) E+a L\right)^2-\frac{\Sigma^2}{\Delta} \dot{r}^2=\frac{1}{\sin ^2(\theta)}\left(a \sin ^2(\theta) E+L\right)^2+\Sigma^2 \dot{\theta}^2-\delta a^2 \cos ^2(\theta) $$
Could someone guide me? I have no idea how to start doing it in Mathematica and the purpose is to use it in more complex expressions.
The code in Mathematica is (I changed for convenience $R = \dot{r}$ and $\Theta = \dot{\theta}$):
Σ[r, θ] = r^2 + a^2*(Cos[θ])^2;
Δ[r] = r^2 + a^2 - 2*M*r;
Y[r, θ] = (r^2 + a^2)^2 - a^2*Δ[r]*(Sin[θ])^2;
Simplify[1 == (δ + ( (Y[r, θ]*EE^2 + 4*a*M*r*EE*L)/(Σ[r, θ]*Δ[r]) ) - ((Δ[r] - a^2*(Sin[θ])^2)/(Σ[r, θ]*Δ[r]*(Sin[θ])^2)) L^2) (Σ[r, θ]/Δ[r] R^2 + Σ[r, θ] Θ^2)]


It will help if you provide Mathematica code of the equation.

By expanding both equations as differences (assuming to be solved for a zero), taking the common numerators and handling
$$(r,\ v_r =\dot r, \ \sin \theta, \ \cos \theta , \  \omega =  \dot \theta ) $$
as an independent set of variables, its easy to see that the both equations have nothing in common.
The scale factors in the Kerr metrics are axially elliptically deformed, so for a separation ansatz elliptcal space coordinates are more suitable.
For a complete account see e.g.
Separation Kerr Metrics
